# SQL Update record when field is in the past

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

how can I set all records in the field "published"=0 whose date in field F12 is older than today?

Unfortunately, the field F12 is not a DateTime field, but a string. Unfortunately, I can't change that. I have to convert the string into a date first.

Unfortunately, this code does not work

```
UPDATE 'mytable' 
SET 'published' = '0' 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('F12', '%d.%m.%Y') DATEDIFF(day, 'F12', NOW()) >= 1
```

A screenshot of phpMyAdmin is here:

[image]

Thank you very much for your support and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect logic like this:

```
update mytable
    set published = 0
    where STR_TO_DATE(F12, '%d.%m.%Y') < curdate();
```

Note that single quotes are being used only for the string constant.  That could be the issue with your query.  Or it could be that you are using `now()` which has a time component so it also updates values whose date is today.

Comment: **where STR_TO_DATE(F12, '%d.%m.%Y') < curdate()** is a full table scan nd cant use a index, MySQL must convert each date field into a date to compare it

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you, it works! With the single quotes, i know what is problem, i use the single quotes for the Editor. I used the following code: UPDATE `mytable` SET `published` = '0' WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`F12`, '%d.%m.%Y') < curdate();

Comment: @Bernd: How i can solve the problem more efficent?

Comment: @fab - the only way is to change the field to date or timestamp and set a index on it

Comment: @fab - i think there is one way more. You can generate a new persitant virtual field in the table where automaticly stored the **STR_TO_DATE(F12, '%d.%m.%Y')** and set a index on this field. then you can compare **F12new < now()**

Comment: @Bernd: My problem is that the records are made by an external software, I can't change that. My script runs with a cronjob at night, so the execution time is secondary.

Comment: @fab - there is nothing to change in the logic. only add a new persitent virtual field. it will filled automaticly. see this from MAriaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/ , but there is a little difference to create one in MySQL vs MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Answer. its only a Sample for virtual fields:

**create a sample table**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `F12` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F12new` date AS (STR_TO_DATE(`F12`, '%d.%m.%Y')) PERSISTENT,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> CREATE TABLE `table1` (   `a` int(11) NOT NULL,   `F12` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,   `F12new` date AS (STR_TO_DATE(`F12`, '%d.%m.%Y')) PERSISTENT ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> insert into table1 (a,F12) VALUES (1,'1.2.2018');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from table1;
+---+----------+------------+
| a | F12      | F12new     |
+---+----------+------------+
| 1 | 1.2.2018 | 2018-02-01 |
+---+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> insert into table1 (a,F12) VALUES (1,'17.05.2029');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from table1;
+---+------------+------------+
| a | F12        | F12new     |
+---+------------+------------+
| 1 | 1.2.2018   | 2018-02-01 |
| 1 | 17.05.2029 | 2029-05-17 |
+---+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Now you only set a index on F12new